# PHP Compare two Associative Arrays by Key

Tags: php, arrays, compare, associative-array

I am trying to compare two PHP arrays, that have different information in them, but both have the same key "id" which im trying to compare against.

First array:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59
            [number] => 0002319411QT17D
            [type] => 2
            [rate] => 1
            [site] => 776
            [reading] => 0.00
            [activity] => 1
            [distance] => 0.000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 60
            [number] => 0000149450TR36E
            [type] => 1
            [rate] => 1
            [site] => 777
            [reading] => 0.00
            [activity] => 1
            [distance] => 0.000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 61
            [number] => 0000112211TR135
            [type] => 1
            [rate] => 2
            [site] => 777
            [reading] => 0.00
            [activity] => 1
            [distance] => 0.000
        )

)
```

I then have this second array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59
            [emp_inv] => 1
            [emp_gen] => 1970-01-01 12:00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59
            [emp_inv] => 2
            [emp_gen] => 1970-01-01 12:00:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59
            [emp_inv] => 3
            [emp_gen] => 1970-01-01 12:00:00
        )

)
```

I simply want to know of the [id] in the first array appears in the second array.

e.g.
[id] => 59 appears in both arrays, but id 60 does not.

I've tried various PHP functions such as array_assoc to get the differences but it just returns blank arrays, not sure if this has something to so with it being an array inside of another array.

Hope someone can help, and thanks :)

Comment: You want to get the difference of your two arrays?

Comment: Not the difference per say, but if an id in the first array, appears in the second. "e.g. [id] => 59 appears in both arrays, but id 60 does not" so this would return true

Comment: Why not do a for loop?

Comment: Can you also post the code?

Comment: Related: [PHP compare two arrays and get the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37479371/2943403)

Comment: [array_uintersect() looks pretty handy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71247577/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the IDs that exist in both arrays using [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (if you're on PHP 5.5 or above):

```
$commonIds = array_intersect(array_column($first, 'id'), array_column($second, 'id'));
```

[Example](https://eval.in/422351). If you're on an earlier version of PHP, [here's an alternative implementation](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php) (recommended from the PHP manual) - or construct something manual using a few loops.

If you then want to check if an ID exists in both arrays, just do `$exists = (in_array(123, $commonIds)); // false`