# PHP compare two arrays and get the difference

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays

```
$original = array(
array('fruit' => 'appel','color' => 'green'),
array('fruit' => 'Banana','color' => 'Yellow'),
array('fruit' => 'orange','color' => 'orange',)
);
```

and

```
$new = array(
array('fruit' => 'appel'),
array('fruit' => 'orange')
);
```

Now i want to compare the two arrays and print out the different one.
In this case i want to keep

```
array('fruit' => 'Banana','color' => 'Yellow')
```

When i use array_intersect_key

```
$original_new = array_intersect_key($new, $original);
```

it's deleting the array i want to keep.
I thought i do this:

```
$original_new = array_intersect_key($new, $original);
$original_new = array_diff($original_new, $original);
```

But this is of course not working.
Can somebody help me out whit this?

Comment: You need array functions or raw code?

Comment: My result for now is that the array('fruit' => 'Banana','color' => 'Yellow') is deleted. But i want that that is the only array i want to keep.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some loop and array. [Check Online](https://3v4l.org/XJfJ5).

First make the array from `$new` array with the column only, and using the foreach loop over the `$original` array just check the fruit is in the `$new` array or not, if not than store the complete sub array in an array name `$arr`.

```
$arr = array();
$com = array_column($new, 'fruit');
foreach($original as $value){
    if(!in_array($value['fruit'], $com)){
        $arr[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($arr); //Array ( [0] => Array ( [fruit] => Banana [color] => Yellow ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a different point of view,

You can get the solution using some array functions

you just need to get [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) fruit of `$new` array and same of `$original` array, get the [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) of the 2 arrays, finally get the [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) ,

just try this:

```
$res = $original[key(array_diff(
       array_column($original,'fruit'), array_column($new,'fruit')))];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without writing own code:

```
$res = array_intersect_key($original, 
            array_diff(array_column($original, 'fruit'), 
                       array_column($new, 'fruit')));
```

[demo](https://eval.in/578159)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"2.00");
$a2=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"2");
$r = array_diff_assoc($a1, $a2);

print_r($r);
```

You can use [array_diff_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)
But note that the comparison is strict (**===**)

The result for the code above:

```
Array
(
    [c] => 2.00
)
```

Answer (score -1):

(PHP 4 >= 4.0.1, PHP 5, PHP 7)
array_diff — Computes the difference of arrays

Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

This will return

```
Array ( [d] => yellow )
```

Comment: Then you can use it with loop or something